# python function returns different results when called repeatedly

Tags: python

When I run the python code below,

```
def main():
    #print prime_factors(10)
    print prime_factors(9)

def prime_factors(n, i=2, factors=[]):
    if n==1:
        return factors
    if(n%i==0):
        factors.append(i)
        n = n/i
        return prime_factors(n, i, factors)
    else:
        return prime_factors(n, i+1, factors)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

it returns the expected results, it returns the prime factors of 9:

```
[3, 3]
```

If I remove the comment from  line 2 "print prime_factors(10)", something strange happens.
For 10 everything is fine, but for 9 it does not only contain the prime factors of 9, but those of 10, as well:

```
[2, 5]
[2, 5, 3, 3]
```

If I call the function with the two optional arguments

```
def main():
    print prime_factors(10, i=2, factors[])
    print prime_factors(9, i=2, factors[])
```

everything works fine.

```
[2,5]
[3,3]
```

I can't figure out why. I suspect this is some issue with scopes, but I just don't understand it :-(
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `Least Astonishment in Python: The Mutable Default Argument` is definitely the #1 reason for duplicate closures of python questions...

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: it's a duplicate, but how are new users supposed to know that from the title?

Comment: @JaceBrowning But those who know this can mark this as duplicate. No need to answer the same question again and again.

Comment: Searching for `[python] default value change` returns that question as 4th result(at least for me).

Answer (score 7):

The default values defined for function arguments are "sticky" - they belong to the function body itself, so when you modify them they stay modified for the next call.

Answer (score 4):

This is because `factors` is a mutable default argument. A new list called `factors` is evaluated only once, and hence if you mutate the list, you get the mutated list in the succeeding calls. See the following snippet -

```
>>> def test(a = []):
        a.append('x')
        return a

>>> test()
['x']
>>> test()
['x', 'x']
```

Try initializing it's default to `None` and then checking on `None` and assigning an empty list within the function body.

```
>>> def test(a = None):
        if a is None:
            a = []
        a.append('x')
        return a

>>> test()
['x']
>>> test()
['x']
```

Answer (score 0):

Having factors=[] as a default value in function argument is not a good idea. Python evalutes the [] expression only once, when it first encounters the function definition. Basicly that means that all you calls to the prime_factors will use same list, and each call will append its own values.

Ex:

```
prime_factors(9)
prime_factors(9)
prime_factors(9)
```

will return

```
[3,3,3,3,3,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

See this question: ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

You want to do something like:

```
...
def prime_factors(n, i=2, factors=None):
    if factors is None:
        factors = [] 
    ...
```